# Erro 405 - Requisição Cross Domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Galera, to fazendo uma requisição da minha pagina no github (tiagosilveiaa.gihub.io) para o meu servidor de testes, só pra executar o Script do form mesmo, porém era me apresentada uma mensagem de que os protocolos eram diferentes (https x http) ""Resolvi"" colocando o endereço da seguinte forma:

Cod:

```
//tiagotestes.esy.es/portfolio/php/envia.php
```

Agora me é apresentada a mensagem 405, que o método é inválido. Como posso resolver isso? Pois eu consigo fazer o POST do meu localhost.

Form:

```
<form id="contato" action="//tiagotestes.esy.es/portfolio/php/envia.php" method="POST">
```

JS:

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {
    if (validar()){
        $.post(
                $("#contato").attr("action"),
                $("#contato").serialize()
            )
            .done(function(retorno) {
                alert(retorno);
                $("#nome").val("");
                $("#email").val("");
                $("#telefone").val("");
                $("#mensagem").val("");

            })
            .fail(function(retorno) {
                alert(retorno)
            });
      }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://tiagosilveiraa.github.io/');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

if ($nome ==""){
  echo("Preencha o campo nome");
  die();
} else if ($email ==""){
  echo("Preencha o campo E-Mail");
  die();
} else if ($telefone ==""){
  echo("Preencha o campo Telefone");
  die();
} else if ($mensagem ==""){
  echo("Preencha o campo Mensagem");
  die();
}

$msgfinal = "Oi, você recebeu uma mensagem enviada pelo formulário do Site<br />
                Esses são os dados do cliente:
                <ul>
                <li><h3>Nome: ". $nome. "</h3></li>
                <li><h3>E-Mail: " .$email. "  </h3></li>
                <li><h3>Telefone: ".$telefone." </h3></li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <p>
                Essa é a mensagem que ele mandou: <br/><br/><blockquote style='border-left: solid 5px #f7ca18; padding-left: 10px;'><i> &nbsp; " .$mensagem.
                "</i></blockquote></p>" ;

// send email
mail("tiago_tmax@hotmail.com","Contato do Site", $msgfinal, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Você já tentou: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: //tiagosilveiraa.github.io/');` ?
Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente 405 indica preflight/OPTIONS request, na qual a solicitacao esta sendo rejeitada pelo servidor em si, e nem chega ao php ou qualquer outra coisa que esteja usando. Vc tem que alterar as configuracoes do apache ou .htaccess